Бот во ВКонтакте
Вопрос такой: допустим я создал сообщество-бота (как Iris-бот например), после добавления его в беседу и выдачи ему прав администратора, могу ли я получить доступ ко всей переписке участников беседы не находясь в ней?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка.

Доброй ночи, поменять его?
